# What is the smallest dimension a non-commutative C*-algebra can have?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

What is the smallest dimension a non-commutative C-star-algebra can have? Let $d$ denote this dimension. Clearly, $d\leq 4$ as $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ is a $4$-dimensional non-commutative C-star-algebra. Also, $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are the only $0$- and $1$-dimensional C*-algebras, respectively, and they are both commutative, thus $d\geq2$. But are there $2$- or $3$-dimensional non-commutative C-star-algebras?

I can't find any examples, so I think $d=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra#Finite-dimensional_C*-algebras).  A finite-dimensional $C^*$ algebra is isomorphic to a direct sum of full matrix algebras.  The smallest noncommutative full matrix algebra is $M(2,\mathbb C)$ which is $4$-dimensional.